# How to prevent uploaded files from having the same name Flask Python

Tags: python, flask, file-upload

I am trying to build a website in python using flask that takes file uploads and saves them to a folder (called uploads). However, when two files with the same name are uploaded, the first one is overwritten by the last one. How can I prevent this in a way that means that I don't lose any files? Would adding a timestamp to the filename help or would there still be an issue if two files are uploaded at the same time?

Thanks!

Filesystem

```
FlaskProject:
├───static
├───templates
├───uploads
└───app.py
```

Html

```
{%extends "base.html" %}
{%block content%}
  
<p>
<h2>Upload Below!</h2>
<div></div>
<form action = "http://localhost:5000/upload_complete" method = "POST"
 enctype = "multipart/form-data">
<input type = "file" name = "file" />
<input type = "submit"/>
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

Python

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, render_template, request
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
import os

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = "D:/Me/FlaskProject/uploads"
@app.route('/upload')
def upload():
    return render_template("upload.html", page="Upload Images")

@app.route('/upload_complete', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_complete():
    if request.method == 'POST':    
        f = request.files['file']
        f.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], secure_filename(f.filename)))
        return redirect(url_for('upload_complete'))
    return render_template("upload_complete.html", page="Upload Complete")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True
    app.run()
    app.run(debug = True)
```

(upload_complete.html is just a thank you screen)

Answer (score 0):

You can generate an `uuid` and update the filename with it.

You can generate `uuid` like this,

```
import uuid

... your code ..
hash_value = uuid.uuid4().hex
f.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], hash_value + secure_filename(f.filename)))
```

Answer (score -1):

Add the timestamp in your code so it generate the output based on timestamp. Therefore, the overwritten is not happening.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).